# Use one List for multiple web pages

Tags: list

I have a webpage with the following code:

```
<td width="178>NAME:</td>
<td><select NAME="NAME" size="1" tabindex="1">
<option selected = true VALUE"">Please Specify</option>
<option VALUE=" Brown Dog">Brown Dog</option>
<option VALUE=" Blue Dog">Blue Dog</option>
<option VALUE=" Big Dog">Big Dog</option>
<option VALUE=" Bad Dog">Bad Dog</option>
...

</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

This same exact code also resides in a number of other pages. When i update one page I have to update all of the other pages as well.

How can i code this information so it shows up in all of my webpages but only have to update it in one place?

Can I store this information in a file and call it in when the webpage is loaded?

Comment: Do you use just plain HTML or any server-side programming to output the HTML, like JSPs or Servlets?

Comment: As far as i can tell it is just plain HTML. These are old internal webpages that were created by someone else a long time ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: I tried this but it does not allow me to pull up the list:


<script>
  $(function(){
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file = 'views/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
      $(this).load(file);
    });
  });
</script>